# “I have been doing this job” vs “since I am doing this job”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, semantic-roles

I am really confused about these two sentences:

> 1:- I have been doing this job for 10 years.
>
> 2:-  It has been 10 years since I am doing this job.

Whether or not these sentences are same, if not then provide me with some help. And one thing more even if I say that I have been waiting for you since 6 hours  is similar to this sentence that it has been six hours since I am waiting for you?

> 3:- Ten years has passed to this event.

Is this sentence correct or wrong?

Comment: I am sure there is a duplicate question but so far all I can find is [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/151665/56820) showing the use of **for** and **since**.

Comment: Related question: [Meaning: “waiting for 6 hours” vs. “6 hours since I was waiting”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/meaning-waiting-for-6-hours-vs-6-hours-since-i-was-waiting)

Answer (score 2):

Your first two sentences are not the same.  The first sentence is correct, but the second is not.

"I am doing this job" is in the present continuous tense, and it is not correct to put it in the second sentence after "since".

We could make the second sentence correct this way:

> It has been ten years since I started this job.

The third sentence is incorrect.  We can fix it this way:

> Ten years have passed since that event.

Please do not use the present continuous tense after *since* when its meaning is *at a time in the past after or later than*.

Correct:

> Dr. Jones has been here since I began waiting for you two hours ago.
>   The weather has been horrible since I got this job.

Incorrect:

> Dr. Jones has been here since I am waiting for you two hours ago.
>   The weather has been horrible since I am doing this job.

Comment: I think your second incorrect example is a bit unclear.  It's technically correct English, but just doesn't mean what it's supposed to mean.  Instead, it means that the speaker's English has improved, and it's because they are doing the job they're talking about.  No reference to time.